# Extract data from kCBAdvDataManufacturerData on Cordova BLE Central Plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, typescript, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I'm using **Cordova BLE Plugin** in ionic3. I'm trying to parse `kCBAdvDataManufacturerData` information from `TI Sensor Tag` by scanning it, before really connecting with it.

When I scan it, I see the below log in Xcode:

```
2017-06-30 12:51:54.308883+0200 MyApp[622:121070] Discovered {
    advertising =     {
        kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
        kCBAdvDataLocalName = "CC2650 SensorTag";
        kCBAdvDataManufacturerData =         {
            CDVType = ArrayBuffer;
            data = "DQADAAA=";
        };
        kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =         (
            AA80
        );
        kCBAdvDataTxPowerLevel = 0;
    };
    id = "F674D953-925E-4371-B273-3468D481E936";
    name = "CC2650 SensorTag";
    rssi = "-39";
}
```

the data field in the `kCBAdvDataManufacturerData` seems to be `base64` encoded, i tried decoding it using the following function:

```
private base64ToBase16(base64) {
  return window.atob(base64)
      .split('')
      .map(function (char) {
        return ('0' + char.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
      })
     .join('')
     .toUpperCase();
}
```

When i try to call like:

```
console.log('stringify:', this.base64ToBase16(device.advertising.kCBAdvDataManufacturerData.data));
```

it doesn't work, it reports

> Error in Success callbackId: BLE251402365 : TypeError: undefined is
>   not an object (evaluating
>   'device.advertising.kCBAdvDataManufacturerData.data')

Can anyone help on how to resolve this. Also what does `CDVType` field in `kCBAdvDataManufacturerData` represents, since I see this field only in few devices, not all devices has this parameter.

Looking forward to hear your suggestions.

Comment: Actually I'm struggling with the same issue. In my case, it's 'kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs'. Because there are many unfinished testing ble devices around me, scanning is not working properly. My suggestion is to modify plugin in Native and that's what I'm going to try.